# How to manage python callbacks executed from a C library in a Qt/PySide6 application?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, thread-safety, pyside6

Before I describe my particular problem, please check my understanding of how Python works with DLLs in general.

I have an existing PySide6 application. When I call `QCoreApplication::exec()`, a Qt event loop starts running. Eventually, a signal gets emitted, and the event loop executes a slot that I define in Python.

The way I imagine this, once we call `exec()`, the python interpreter basically doesn't do anything until a slot defined in Python needs to execute. So, the Qt event loop, which "lives" in the QtCore dll, starts iterating, and the interpreter is still alive, but is blocked from doing anything. If I look at the system in [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), I can see a Python process containing several threads. One of them has a start address of `Qt6Core.dll!QThread::start`, a few are `ucrtbase.dll`, several are `ntdll.dll`, and one is `python.exe`.

If no signals are being emitted and no slots are being executed, my understanding is that the python interpreter can't do anything at all. It can only run if Qt tells it to, even to do background things like collect garbage or service OS signals.

> Question 1: Is all of that correct?

At some point, a signal (Qt signal, not OS signal) will be emitted, and a slot will need to execute. When a slot is defined in Python, the Qt event loop will need to somehow execute that slot's Python code, and that code will need to have access to all the variables and things in the interpreter's environment.

> Question 2: When that slot gets executed, what is happening to the Qt and Python threads? I imagine that the Qt event loop's thread tells the interpreter's thread to run some chunk of code, and the Qt thread just needs to sit and wait for the interpreter to finish executing it. Is that what's happening? Or does Qt's thread actually execute the interpreter's code somehow? Can each one block the other from executing?

My application needs a new feature now, and we need to use another library to talk to some hardware. There is a Python wrapper around the hardware's C library, and this wrapper lets us specify callbacks in python to be executed when the hardware detects an event. When I run this, another thread shows up in the list in Process Explorer, so the hardware's DLL must kick off another thread to poll for events. When something happens in that thread, it executes the Python callback, in which I print out the thread's ID (listed in Process Explorer as the hardware library's thread) and emit a Qt signal. When a slot connected to that signal executes, the thread ID printed is the one listed in Process Explorer as python.exe's thread.

> Question 3: Both the slot and the callback are Python functions. Why does one execute in the python interpreter's thread while the other executes in the hardware DLL's thread? I would expect that both of them would execute in the interpreter's thread, or they'd both execute in the threads of their respective DLLs (Qt and the hardware library). Are there different ways for DLLs to "call" the Python interpreter? And could this just be an artifact of how the logger module's [`%(thread)d` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) works?

So the question that actually brought me here:

> Both the hardware callback and the Qt slot can manipulate variables in the Python environment, so I have to assume that I need to use some thread synchronization mechanism. Can I use Python's `threading.Lock` object (note that in this application I'm not currently using the `threading` module at all)? Would I need to use Qt's mutex objects? Or does it not matter at all?

One thing I've considered is just not putting the hardware interaction into the application at all. Instead, I could have all hardware operations in a separate python application from the PySide GUI. Then they could talk to each other via TCP or a named pipe, and it would avoid all of this. However, there's obviously a lot I don't understand about how all these threads are handled, so I'd like to learn a little first and be able to make a more informed decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Cpython interpreter is not "living" in a different thread, it is just a dll, that has C functions that can be called by any application, this dll also has a few global structs which hold information like the loaded modules and the variables in them, these structs are accessible by any thread in the application through the dll functions.

> If no signals are being emitted and no slots are being executed, my
> understanding is that the python interpreter can't do anything at all.
> It can only run if Qt tells it to, even to do background things like
> collect garbage or service OS signals.

you are mostly correct, checking OS signals and garbage collection are done by the interpreter on each step in the execution of the python bytecode, if python  bytecode isn't executing (as in you are stuck in a C library or blocked by a lock) then you won't be able to do them.

> When that slot gets executed, what is happening to the Qt and Python threads? I imagine that the Qt event loop's thread tells the interpreter's thread to run some chunk of code, and the Qt thread just needs to sit and wait for the interpreter to finish executing it. Is that what's happening?

No, it's all just a single thread, launching `python.exe` creates a single thread, this same thread calls the C++ function that runs the QT eventloop, and when the slot is fired this same thread calls the C function that will execute the python bytecode, think about the interpreter as just a fancy C function that parses strings and calls other C functions, and QT as another fancy C function, and they just end up calling one another.

> Both the slot and the callback are Python functions. Why does one
> execute in the python interpreter's thread while the other executes in
> the hardware DLL's thread?

because in the slot case, it was the `python.exe` thread that called the C function to execute python bytecode, while in the other case it was the dll thread that called another function in the python dll (a wrapper) to execute python bytecode, a C function (Cpython) can be executed by any thread in the process.

> Both the hardware callback and the Qt slot can manipulate variables in
> the Python environment, so I have to assume that I need to use some
> thread synchronization mechanism.

yes, there is already one, it's called the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), it is a lock that all the functions that are executing python bytecode have to lock before they start executing python bytecode and have to release that lock when they are no-longer executing python bytecode, this is automatically done by QT, ctypes, and other binding APIs like pybind11, but if you are calling into the python dll manually then you will have to make sure you are [Acquiring and Releasing the GIL](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock) before and after executing python bytecode, as the python interpreter will fail if the GIL wasn't locked and you may run into deadlocks if you don't properly release that lock.

Comment: This is a great, well-thought-out answer, thank you! I will challenge the last paragraph, as I am hesitant to rely on the GIL as a thread-synchronization object. A Qt mutex or a threading.Lock still seems like a good idea. My question was if one was more appropriate than the other, but based on the rest of the info here, my assessment is that either one should work.

Answer (score 2):

You got some things right, but others are imprecise or caused by wrong understanding of threading.

### The Qt thread - aka, the (theoretically) main thread

First of all: the Qt *application* thread *is* the main thread, and it is exactly the same of python, or, to be precise, the thread in which the Qt application was created. Note that it is theoretically possible to create and run a Qt application in a different thread than the main one as long as it is the *first ever* created QObject (or the first created QObject is in that thread), as partially explained in this [Qt forum post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/124878/running-qapplication-exec-from-another-thread-qcoreapplication-qguiapplication).

That said, Qt may spawn *other* threads depending on many factors. For instance:

- on Linux, there is often a thread related to the DBus interface;
- QFileSystemModel has its own thread for populating the contents of the directories;
- the QtWebEngine view/page classes may create further threads;
- printing involves usage of external libraries, which normally create at least one further thread from the OS;

### The interpreter is *not* blocked

What is blocked is the further processing of anything that could be executed *after* the "line" that starts the event loop of the Qt application, but that does not mean that it is "blocked". If you started another thread before that, anything in that thread would be executed without any issue, including garbage collection (as long as the collected objects only have references in that thread).

Interestingly enough, the other thread could potentially *block* the main thread instead.

### The event loop

It is called *event* loop, not *signal* loop: signals are not events. Signals can only be emitted as a consequence of an event.

The loop keeps waiting until an event "happens". Then Qt decides, based on the event type, what to do.

There are many types of events: user input from keyboard/mouse, a system event (for instance, a window gets activated after the window of another program is closed or minimized), timers, etc.

Depending on the event, signals *may* be emitted by the QApplication or by any other object that would eventually handle that event. For input events, Qt sends the event to the currently focused widget (or the one under the cursor for mouse events), if it handles it and has a signal that may depend on it, the signal would be emitted: for instance when typing something on a QLineEdit, the `textChanged` signal is emitted.

### What happens when a python function is called by a signal

As said above, the *main* Qt thread is (normally) the same of the python interpreter. Assuming that the signal was emitted from the main thread (for instance, the `textChanged` case above), Qt *calls* the connected function; the fact that it's a python function and not a "C++ one" is irrelevant: functions are routines that are accessed using a memory address, Python wrappers like PyQt and PySide "expose" the python function so that Qt knows that it has to "call" it (things are a bit more complex, but let's keep this simple for the sake of explanation).

Now, what happens when the signal is emitted from a thread that is different from the receiver? Well, that depends, and we need a further point.

### Python `Thread` and Qt `QThread` are *not* "the" thread

A common misconception is that the Python `Thread` and Qt `QThread` classes "are" the thread.
They are *not*.

A thread is a component of a process: each process always at least one thread, since it's the basic component of a process. It's like thinking about groups of people: a group of people implicitly has *at least* one person.

A thread executes some instructions as managed by the OS scheduler. Long story short, the above [Q]Thread objects are not "the threads", they are *interfaces* to the OS threading capabilities.

What those objects do is to provide a way to run certain instructions *in* a thread. Those instructions are normally implemented in the respective `run()` override of a subclass, or, alternatively, by providing a reference to the `target` function in the case of `Thread`, or by connecting the `started` signal of a QThread to the function (assuming that it *belongs* to that thread, more on that later).

What they do *not* do is to run those functions/instructions on their own: you do *not* call the `run()`. Calling `start()` will, by telling the OS to do *eventually* do that, through its threading API (to which Python interfaces with).

This is an important aspect to consider: everything that is *directly* executed from those functions is done in that thread. That's why you can *never* directly call a function of a UI element from a thread: UI elements are *not* thread safe (by default, no Qt class and function is, unless it *explicitly* provides such support), and if you call a function of a non thread-safe object from an external thread, it will probably fail in some way.

The above aspect is extremely important to remember, as a common beginner mistake is to think that, just because an object "exists" in the main thread (like a Qt widget), it is safe to call its functions from another thread.

That is just *wrong*: a function called from another thread will *always* be executed in that same thread. That's why signals are important.

### Signals and slots in different threads

By default, Qt uses the `AutoConnection` type when signals and slots/functions are connected. This means that it will use [thread affinity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#thread-affinity) to know whether *the signaller thread* is the same as *the receiver thread*. Note the terminology: what's important is *from what thread* the signal comes and *to what thread* the function belongs.

The receiver thread can only be *assumed*: if it's a function of a QObject (like a QWidget slot), it would be that QObject's thread.

The signaller is *the thread from which the signal was emitted*. Consider the previous section: you may emit the signal of an object that was created in thread X, but from the thread Y. What matters is what finally calls the signal's `emit()`.

Also, QObjects always belong to the thread in which they are created, and that's why we must use `moveToThread()`: that changes the "thread ownership", and then their *thread affinity* properly matches the thread in which their connected functions would be executed.

Finally, when the *affinity* of signals and slots detects that they are in different threads, Qt *queues* them. The signals (and the objects used in their arguments) will then be put on hold for that receiver, and the connected slots will only be called when control returns to the event loop of its thread.

That is exactly what you describe in question #3.

### Lifespan and usage of objects across threads

If shared across threads, mutable objects should obviously be carefully treated (or, threaded ;-) ).

Considering your situation, using *both* callbacks *and* signals may be a problem if they use the same objects. While using lock and mutex object is certainly a solution, you may need to consider if that is really necessary.

If the related objects do not really need special, ehm, *threadment* (you only *mutate* them in the same thread), there's no need for that: what you only need is to properly *encapsulate* a "controller" QObject that will be used as an interface with the hardware API.

### A basic example

I have prepared a basic example that tries to consider all the above aspects. It has a simple `HardwareApi` class that represents a possible API interface that runs its own thread and fakes polls of "virtual events": it randomly creates events that would eventually trigger a callback (if set) and wait some random time until the next one, unless a stop has been requested.

Then I created a basic QObject subclass that implements its own signals, manages the API object, and "registers" its signals as callbacks for the event and the exit of the API itself.
Note that the creation of a QObject subclass is mandatory to provide custom signals, since Qt signals (like Qt slots and Qt properties) can only be valid if created as class members of a QObject.

The interesting thing is that, by using `signal.emit` as a callback, the signals are actually emitted from the API thread, which allows Qt to *know* that the "signaller" is in a different thread (this should potentially work with lambdas as well, but you have to be very careful about that).

The important aspect here is that we don't need a further thread (or QThread) at all, as Qt is perfectly able to handle all this by checking the thread affinity based on the related objects: the "signaller" (the thread of the API that finally emits the signal) and the "receiver" (the UI object).

```py
import sys
from random import randrange
from threading import Thread, Event

from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class MyEvent(object):
    def __init__(self, wait, nextWait):
        self.wait = wait
        self.nextWait = nextWait


class HardwareAPI(object):
    _eventCallback = _finishedCallback = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.stopper = Event()

    def event(self, event):
        if self._eventCallback:
            try:
                self._eventCallback(event)
            except (TypeError, RuntimeError) as e:
                print(type(e), e)

    def finished(self):
        if self._finishedCallback:
            try:
                self._finishedCallback()
            except (TypeError, RuntimeError) as e:
                print(type(e), e)

    def run(self):
        self.keepRunning = True
        wait = 2
        self.event(MyEvent(0, wait))
        while self.keepRunning:
            if self.stopper.wait(wait):
                break
            nextWait = randrange(1, 10)
            self.event(MyEvent(wait, nextWait))
            wait = nextWait
        self.finished()

    def setEventCallback(self, callback):
        self._eventCallback = callback

    def setFinishedCallback(self, callback):
        self._finishedCallback = callback

    def start(self):
        Thread(target=self.run).start()

    def stop(self):
        self.keepRunning = False
        self.stopper.set()


class QtHardwareAPI(QObject):
    eventSignal = Signal(MyEvent)
    finished = Signal()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.api = HardwareAPI()
        self.api.setEventCallback(lambda e: self.eventSignal.emit(e))
        self.api.setFinishedCallback(self.finished.emit)

    def start(self):
        self.api.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.api.stop()


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(480, 320)

        monofont = QFont()
        monofont.setFamily('monospace')
        self.timerLabel = QLabel(font=monofont)
        self.log = QPlainTextEdit(readOnly=True, font=monofont)
        self.stopButton = QPushButton('Stop!')

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.timerLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.log)
        layout.addWidget(self.stopButton)

        self.clockTimer = QTimer(interval=24, timeout=self.updateTimer)
        self.elapseTimer = QElapsedTimer()

        self.api = QtHardwareAPI()

        self.api.eventSignal.connect(self.eventReceived)
        self.api.finished.connect(self.apiFinished)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.api.stop)

        self.clockTimer.start()
        self.elapseTimer.start()
        self.api.start()

    def eventReceived(self, event):
        nextWait = self.elapseTimer.elapsed() + event.nextWait * 1000
        nextTime = QTime.fromMSecsSinceStartOfDay(nextWait)
        self.log.appendPlainText('Event after {}s, next in {}s ({})'.format(
            event.wait, event.nextWait, 
            nextTime.toString('HH:mm:ss')
        ))

    def apiFinished(self):
        self.clockTimer.stop()
        self.log.appendPlainText('API has stopped')

    def updateTimer(self):
        t = QTime.fromMSecsSinceStartOfDay(self.elapseTimer.elapsed())
        self.timerLabel.setText(t.toString('HH:mm:ss.zzz'))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Test()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```